# Populating <select></select> with a large number of values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a web form which has the user input the values of certain characteristics, however some of the characteristics have up to 45000 values.

The selects were working earlier, albeit with a slight amount of lag when populating the dropdown and trying to scroll through it fast, but now it does not populate at all and the web form hangs.

Is there a way to efficiently contain this many values into a dropdown? Also which is the best library for searchable comboboxes?

I looked at this implementation as it has a "load on open" feature which I thought might be beneficial, but it did not seem to work and is no longer actively developed.
http://john-oc.github.io/

Thanks

Comment: You're going above and beyond the intended use of a select tag!

Comment: Nobody can visually handle that many selections. You need a different UI like auotocomplete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to use an autocomplete feature instead of a select menu in this case. A user can type in the first few characters, causing a request to start filtering results based on their input.

Here are a couple of really good autocomplete plugins:

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Roll your own:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg16/index.html

Comment: There are numerous angular modules also without needing jQuery dependency

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Todd, I think you might want some solution that has autocomplete to hide too many results. I'd even go a step further and suggest bootstrap DataTables: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

You can make searchable tables with this, with the key advantage being that it paginates results, so you don't see it all at once.

Comment: I think for the functionality needed an autocomplete would work best, but this datatable is exactly what I need for the next thing I have to implement,   how does one use a bootstrap element in angular?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select. You can have it make a request based on the current text input, and then populate the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is already answered, please let me just contribute here.

You can use the [typeaheads](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads) from [angularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) to achieve this. Beyond the easy manipulation of data, you can even use to make *async* calls using data provider.